# How do I search for .gif image on my S3?

Tags: internet

I want to find a particular .gif but I only have phone access.  Can Google images search for .gifs or just images?  I can't see an option to upload a.gif and try to find where it came from...is it possible?  I have a .gif and I want to find the source on my S3?

OS: 4.1

Comment: +0. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

GOOGLE GOGGLE app can Help to upload a image 
Google Search By Image [APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bjbinc.searchbyimage)

Open Google image in your Default or Chrome browser

1st Method

type filetype:gif [your query] or inurl:gif [your query] then Tap Search

result will be in .gif format

2nd Method

Open Google image in your Default or Chrome browser

then Tap More > Type > choose Animated

[image: Screenshot how to search .gif image in android phones]

Comment: But how do I upload the .gif? I think I confused a concept.  I want to upload a .gif and find out where else on the internet I can see the same .gif.

Comment: look at the answer again you might get what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I just found the alternative solution using [Search by image](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.searchbyimage.app) app. This app lets you search by image on your smartphone. you can upload your photos (.gif or others) in your album to search via Google easily. I already test searching .gif file. it normally works.

Comment: App Install : 500 - 1,000; Latest reviews from May 2015 only. This answer seems to be spam. I could be wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you have an image on your smartphone that you want to find on the internet than NarenderNishad's answer should help.

If you mean by "only phone access" that you do not have a data connection then you will need to extract the .gif from your phone to a PC or other internet enabled device. You can use a USB cable, or bluetooth or NFC connection depending on what your device supports.

If you have or can get to WIFI access then you can connect to the web and from there upload to Google+ or Facebook or imgur or another image repository.